# Enable + Disable Auto-Layout Constraints

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a simple (I think) problem: I have a `UIImageView`, which I have set multiple constraints for in the storyboard.

At times, I'll need to disable the constraints, and set its `frame` manually, but later, I'll want to re-enable those constraints and have the view return to where it was as decided by the constraints.

I thought I could do this with something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func example() { 

    //to set its location and size manually
    imageView.removeConstraint(constraint) 
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(...)

    //to cause it to return to its original position
    imageView.addConstraint(constraint) 

}
```

With this, however, I get the error `2015-08-26 01:14:55.417 Constraints[18472:923024] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb72815f90 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fbb72814c20]-(100)-[UIImageView:0x7fbb72814540]>`. Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Adding the constraints instead to `view` by calling `self.view.addConstraint(...)` gets rid of the error, but still doesn't bring the image view back to where it should be.

I notice I don't even have to remove nor deactivate constraints to be able to set the frame of the `imageView` without problem, so long as I don't call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)`.

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021044/programmatically-disable-auto-layout-constraint?answertab=votes#tab-top) question, but the answer seems unnecessarily complicated, perhaps outdated, and even inapplicable.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368440/can-i-disable-autolayout-for-a-specific-subview-at-runtime) question, but this doesn't cover constraints can be re-enabled—only how they can be disabled.

**Trying to set the `active` property:**

```
self.top.active = false
self.right.active = false
self.bottom.active = false
self.left.active = false
    
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
```

This actually just results in `imageView` being no longer visible. (If I don't set all the constraints' `active` property to false, however, `imageView` moves to the proper position.

The real problem, though, is that when I try to have the image view return to where it was, by setting all the constraints' `active` property to true, nothing happens—the imageView stays where it was (in this case as specified by `imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)`.

Also, it seems, according to my testing and Joachim Bøggild's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494542/when-can-i-activate-deactivate-layout-constraints), that when a constraint's `active` property is set to false, that constraint becomes nil, and thus cannot be re-activated.

**Adding constraints to an array and activating/deactivating them:**

Interestingly, this causes almost exactly the same issues as setting the `active` property. Placing all the constraints in an array `array`, then calling `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(array)` makes the image view disappear. Also, re-activating the constraints later with      `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(array)` doesn't have the image view return to where it should—it stays where it was.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Aha!

Constraints become nil (and thus can't be reactivated), once their `active` property is set to false. Making them **strong references** (thanks, Caleb, for clearing up the nomenclature) preserves them so they can be activated and deactivated as desired.

Comment: If anybody is wondering how to make an `IBOutlet` strong: just remove the `weak` keyword, and voila: your reference is strong!

Answer (score 36):

If you look at the docs for `NSLayoutConstraint` you'll find a section called [*Activating and Deactivating Constraints*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010628-CH1-DontLinkElementID_8) that describes the [`active` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/active), which in turn tells you:

> You can activate or deactivate a constraint by changing this property...Activating or deactivating the constraint calls addConstraint: and removeConstraint: on the view that is the closest common ancestor of the items managed by this constraint. Use this property instead of calling addConstraint: or removeConstraint: directly.

So, once you've got a **`strong`** reference to the constraint in question (such as you have with your outlet), you can simply set it's `active` property to `false` (or `NO` in Obj-C) to disable, or `true` (or `YES`) to enable.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thanks for your input! I tried this, but ran into a few issues, which I described in an edit above.

Comment: It also seems that when a constraint's `active` is set to false, that constraint becomes nil and thus cannot be reactivated.

Comment: Ah, got it. Making the outlets for the constraints strongly typed fixed it—I can now activate and deactivate them properly.

Comment: Strong references, not strongly typed. That makes sense, because the docs say that changing the `active` property removes the constraint, which means that the view the constraint was attached to no longer does. With no strong references, the constraint would be deallocated. Making your outlet strong avoids that.

Comment: @Randoms making outlets to be `strong` is actually the correct answer, at least it was my problem. You should post it as an answer, rather that as a comment that's hard to find. Or update it as part of the question itself.

Comment: @i4niac Fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

Connect Constraint as IBOutlet  from storyboard to ViewController and create an Array add All constraint in array.

Deactivate those Constraint when not in uses.

Add constraint whenever in uses.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint1;
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2;
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint3;
NSArray *arr = @[constraint1,constraint2,constraint3];
 [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:arr];

//After deactivate constraint array add what ever frame you want to add

//Activate  lateroN
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:arr];
```

Comment: Hi Kavita Asija, I tried this too, well, a Swift-rendition of it, and ran into some issues, which I added in an edit above.

Comment: - (void)updateConstraintsIfNeeded
- (void)updateConstraints
- (BOOL)needsUpdateConstraints 
- (void)setNeedsUpdateConstraints    Update View Constraints after apply active and deactivate Constraints..