# How to switch between two auto-layout constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two UI layout constraints that are conflicting with each other by design. Only one of could be active at a time.

In `UIViewController's` method `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, I have the following code which toggles between the two constraints, depending on the state of a data model.

```
override func updateConstraintsIfNeeded() {
    super.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    if question?.thumbURL != nil {
        showAttachmentConstraint.active = true
        hideAttachmentConstraint.active = false        
    } else {
        showAttachmentConstraint.active = false
        hideAttachmentConstraint.active = true
    }
}
```

This work as intended, but I got this familiar warning in the debug output:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. ...

Apparently when the statement `showAttachmentConstraint.active = true` is executed, it temporarily conflicts with `hideAttachmentConstraint` which is still active at that time.

Is it possible to make this toggle operation atomic? I'm hoping there is something like `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` in `UITableView`.

Comment: Are you sure two constraints is what you need? Can you not just have one and manipulate it in code instead? Anyway, try inverting the order of operations in the first if branch, that way you first disable the unnecessary constraint, and then enable the one you want. Between the two statements, you have no constraints active at the same time.

Comment: Try to put it inside UIView animation block. ;)

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26022729/2177402)

Comment: @Morpheu5 Good question. So I ended up going with the one constraint approach and manipulate the constant as you suggested. And your suggestion to arrange the order of constraints activation/deactivation is clever, although I haven't yet to confirm if works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could change the priority of one of the conflicting constraints to 999 instead of 1000. so you do not even have any problems at design time.

Comment: Changing priorities should really be a last resort kind of thing. It's best to have the fewest constraints possible, and manipulate them instead. This makes it easier to reason about them.

Comment: you should not misuse it. but i don't see a problem in using it in this case. as the official documentation states: `[...]This combination of inequalities, equalities, and priorities gives you a great amount of flexibility and power. By combining multiple constraints, you can define layouts that dynamically adapt as the size and location of the elements in your user interface change.[...]`

Comment: This is indeed a simple enough case that will likely cause no headaches. I'm just saying that, in more complex cases, you might want to first look at other, clearer alternatives before tinkering with priorities. They are less apparent, and thus, if not properly documented, they can easily go unnoticed and forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

Always first deactivate some constraints and then activate the other constraints:

```
override func updateConstraintsIfNeeded() {
    super.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

    if question?.thumbURL != nil {
        hideAttachmentConstraint.active = false
        showAttachmentConstraint.active = true
    } else {
        showAttachmentConstraint.active = false
        hideAttachmentConstraint.active = true
    }
}
```

Comment: what if these constraints are stored inside `UIViewController`?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov, What about it? It should be the same.

Comment: Now I have understood. It seems the app tries to check constraints after each constraint change but anyways the final result will be ok.

Comment: This can be reduced from 7 to 2 lines of code (without explicit if-statements). `hideAttachment...active = question.thumbURL == nil` and `showAttachment...active = question.thumbURL != nil`.

Comment: @Sti, If you do this, if `question.thumbURL` is `nil`, the `hideAttachment` constraint will be activated first, which is exactly the problem described in the question.

Comment: You're right, I'm dumb. Didn't read the actual question or answer (came here by googling something else), but definitely didn't know the order of activation/deactivation was important. Glad to have learned something!

Comment: @Sti, No, you're not, we all make mistakes :) Really glad I could help you.